# Setup user1 to su to user2 only (with password authentication)

Tags: su

How can we setup user1, and other users who belong to group1, `su` to user2. User2's account password must be known to allow the switch.

Comment: You've already got your answer but bear in mind that if user1 has sudo privileges this is negated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal behavior, there is no need to setup anything.